# httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result not working when deployed on Godaddy

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, httpclient, tls1.2, godaddy-api

Problem:
httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result is not working. The code is working fine on localhost. But not working after deployment on GoDaddy.

Below is my code which is working fine in localhost, but after deploying to Godaddy, httpClient is not working even I have set the SecurityProtocolType.Tls12.

```
public class MyWebClientServices
{
    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public T PrepareWebClient<T>(string preparedURL)
    {
        try
        {
          // As my server is using TLS1.2 I kept only that protocol
          ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

          httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
          httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualtiyHeaderValue("application/json");
          var json = httpClient.GetStringAsync(preparedURL).Result;
          //here T is generic PCR class. I have created generic classes for which I need to invoke httpClient & their respective urls as I want to use this same code for all.

          T tJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
          return (T)Convert.ChangeType(tJson, typeof(T));

         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
            throw e;
         }
    }

}//end of MyWebClientServices class
```

In localhost I'm getting data fine.
preparedURL is hosted on a server where it has 128AES TLS1.2 SSL.
After deploying code in Godaddy & when I'm trying to access the data, below error is coming

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond


[SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +6723762
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.]
   System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +6693442
   System.Net.TlsStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +219
   System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41

   [WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +638
   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +65

   [HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
```

I tried to search a lot related to this but getting only SMTP related questions & answers where in my issue is different and I'm not able to find any similar question hence asking it here.

Please help me how would I fix it in GoDaddy.
My hosting is shared hosting.
SSL - Cloudflare SSL
I checked with enabling disabling SSL but still issue same.

Comment: Could there be a port that needs to be opened on your hosted server?

Comment: Can you try it with another URL, like some simple public json API? Also, while it is good you are using a shared `HttpClient`, the `DefaultRequestHeaders` property is not thread safe. You should use a `HttpRequestMessage` and do a `SendAsync`. Not saying that is your problem, but there's a remote chance if you are using the http client elsewhere at the same instant.

Comment: Thanks Crowcoder. My json web api working fine in browser as well as in my localhost code. But after deploying on godaddy error is coming. I tried other web api's too, all are working fine in localhost but in godaddy not a single webapi working. Dont know how would I fix TLS1.2 on godaddy.

Comment: I would suspect it's an environmental issue, not a code issue. If you are comfortable doing this **briefly, just for testing**, try disabling certificate validation: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;`

Comment: Yeah was thinking the same but then it will accept any certificate as valid. Doing it on prod is kind a risky one. Ok let me give a try and will get back here. Something on godaddy stopping to use TLS1.2 or protocol not matching and server is refusing connection. But due to shared hosting dont know what setting I can change and customer care is also not picking up calls.

Comment: You do have access to IIS at a certain level in the GoDaddy portal. Keep trying with to contact support.

Comment: Tried the ValidateCallback code but its also not working in godaddy. :(